# Nginx Location directives, what is the effect of trailing or prepended slashes?

Tags: nginx, config

I.e., what is the difference between

```
location somefolder {

}
```

and

```
location somefolder/ {

}
```

and

```
location /somefolder {

}
```

and

```
location /somefolder/ {

}
```

I know it's kind of a silly question but honestly sometimes I get myself confused, a concise answer would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer.

The first two configurations will not match anything, because every location starts with a "`/`".  So they are basically invalid locations.  A commenter on Server Overflow mentioned this and it proved to be correct.

The second two, for most purposes, are equivalent, in that NGINX will 301 redirect the third to the fourth.  So a request for `http://somedomain/somefolder` will be redirected to `http://somedomain/somefolder/`.  If you really have a location called /somefolder, such as a file literally called that, then you could create a location with the "`=`" operator, which forces an exact match, so

```
location = /somefolder {

}
```

For best practice just always use the `/somefolder/` format unless you really need the exception I just mentioned.